# Mutli tenant app with onion architecture and multiple presentations

Tags: clean-architecture, onion-architecture

Currently I started designing a new multi tenant SaaS application based on the onion architecture in C#

Using a rest web API to expose my services and consume them on 3 platforms. Two web apps (one for the tenants) and one for the tenant's clients and a mobile application for the tenants.

I was thinking the 3 apps could use the same API but I'm running into some issues as I also have some deamons that should run on the server and add data (incoming mails, SMS, phonecalls, ..) via the API and the deamons needs a different way of authenticating etc.

Is it possible to use the same application core services in different presentation layers or is it "not done"?

Currently out of guesses on which route to go and can't seem to find the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to use the same application core services in different presentation layers or is it "not done"?

When looking from 10000 feet down, just about any organisation that offers both a web-application and a native mobile application is doing exactly that. So, it is very much possible and might even be called "standard practice".

You could offer two different API's for the front-ends on the one hand and the daemon services on the other, or if there is a considerable overlap, you could use a single API that accepts multiple mechanisms with which users can authenticate themselves.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it was done this way but leaves me with the question on where to do my mapping etc. If I do it in the API then it will be different for every API or daemon service.

Comment: @Jesse, what do you mean with doing your mapping? If I can use either an email or an SMS to perform some action (e.g. create a support ticket), then both daemons should use the same API to do that.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. I meant upon querying data there is a need to add additional fields (for example. client list with extra info like open balance, primary address) to the GET request and I'm unsure where to place this. In the API layer means I will need to duplicate the mapping if I need to add an API later on, but if I do in the in the service layer I'm stuck with the same mapping for every API.

Comment: @Jesse, you could also provide the information from the Service layer and then filter it out in the API if the caller isn't allowed to see it. Or you can use query parameters to indicate (extra?) fields that should be included in the response. And there are more possibilities.